# Deleting a scheduled message from Azure service bus without using code?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-storage-explorer, service-bus-explorer

I know I can delete an Azure service bus queue scheduled message from code, but I'm looking for a way to do it with a tool. ex. Azure Storage Explorer, Service Bus Explorer, etc.

It doesn't seem like any of the tools allow this?

Comment: Powershell? That's scripting 

Comment: to be honest, I don't really feel like installing powershell on my Mac. You would think one of the gui tools would allow this?

Comment: You can :) I'll post the answer

Comment: which gui tool? I can't do it in the Azure portal. Only 'receiveanddelete' are allowed on active messages, not scheduled messages. I don't believe Storage Explorer allows you to do it either, but maybe I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: ServiceBus Explorer can [Peek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dDxh.png) one or more scheduled messages by sequence number, it can't delete.

Comment: Code or script is the only way :)

Comment: uuuggghhhhh!!!!!!!!

Comment: How about using rest API and postman to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

As Sean Feldman said in the comment, there is no ready tools to achieve your requirement, you need to achieve it by code or script.

Comment: Why would this be so limited?

Answer (score 0):

QueueExplore can display and delete scheduled messages. Or reschedule them. Or perform any other typical operation like move, copy, etc.

https://www.cogin.com/QueueExplorer/azure-service-bus/

However, I see that Mac is mentioned in the comments, QueueExplorer is currently Windows only (and Linux with Wine).